# Objects to be disposed in SharePoint

Tags: dispose, memory-leak, spdisposechecker

I am referring to the following link for disposing the SharePoint objects. Basically, I understand that mainly SPSite and SPWeb are the 2 objects that use unmanaged code.

[Best Practices: Using Disposable Windows SharePoint Services Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa973248.aspx)

I have a Windows Service that loops through all the web applications, then site collections within it and then the sub sites in it. In this, I am carefully disposing SPSite and SPWeb objects. Still there appears to be memory leaks, which I am not able to catch. I tried using SPDisposeCheck, but it doesn't seem to be reliable. I know about SPCAF, but it is paid. I am not sure if there are other tools which are free and reliable for checking memory leaks. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

**Are there other tools which are free and reliable for checking memory leaks.**

Yes, Microsoft provides a tool called the [“Microsoft SharePoint Online Code Analysis Framework (MSOCAF)”](https://caf.sharepoint.microsoftonline.com/) that is available in a SharePoint 2010 and a SharePoint 2013 version.

For more details about `MSOCAF` check https://caf.sharepoint.microsoftonline.com/

**But** what I think it'll give you a similar result as `SPDisposeCheck` result. So I suggest requesting a free `SPCAF` trial for at https://trial.spcaf.com/ and compare the result with `MSOCAF`.

For more details check [(MSOCAF) and (SPCAF) features comparison](https://www.spcaf.com/msocaf-vs-spcaf/?__hstc=237503135.52570be4712c36704483197883dc920e.1490028210708.1490028210708.1490028210708.1&__hssc=237503135.2.1490028210709&__hsfp=967163343)